# Call an API that returns a file

Tags: c#, api, restsharp

I already have an endpoint as follows:

```
[Route("sampleroute/getxl")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetXLTransactionSummaries()
{
    var data = await _service.GetExcelFileByDateAndBranchCode();

    return File(data, "application/octet-stream", sampleFilename);
}
```

My problem is that I do not know how to call this from my c# application. I know how to call APIs that return classes. I got the following code in calling APIs:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Net;

......

public File SampleMethod(//I want a File return type
    var client = new RestClient(BaseURL);

    var request = new RestRequest($"{Endpoint}/sampleroute/getxl", Method.GET);

    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer sample-bearer-08937249");

    client.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;

    var response = client.Execute(request);

    if (response.ErrorException != null) throw new Exception("", response.ErrorException);

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
            return response.Content; //not sure about this

    else throw new Exception($"An error has occurred while calling the API: {response.Content}");//I am not sure about this either
}
```

This is my button, trying to receive the file:

```
private void Sample_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    File file = SampleMethod();
}
```

What should be the right way to do this?

Comment: Can you read your `response.Content` as a `Stream`? You should probably have something like this: `response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()`

Comment: It says 'string' does not contain a definition for ReadAsStreamAsync

Comment: Ok. What is `RestClient`?

Comment: `response.RawBytes` should contain the file.